# Как число из 4 СС перевести в 11 СС

Tags: системы-счисления

Как число из 4 СС перевести в 11 СС? Например с 2 СС в 8 СС всё понятно, ну то есть такие преобразования ясны где можно основание СС в которую преобразовываем выразить через основание исходной СС. Например для 2^3 = 8 и т.п.

Comment: В php есть ф-я [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: @sergiks а в других языках другие методы и что? Автор же не инструмент спрашивает.

Comment: @Genson, в комментариях к доке по intval есть альтернативные примеры реализации перевода, из которых можно понять принципы. В полном отрыве от программирования этот вопрос на форум "Математика".

Comment: @sergiks Вам надо было это сразу указать и никто слово против Вам бы не сказал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не секрет, зачем Вам?
[Вот общее описание перевода.](http://www.csu.ac.ru/~yan/informat/tutor1/pervod_files/perqp.htm)

Comment: по предмету компьютерная арифметика

Comment: блин. то ли я дурак, то ли хороший педагог писал...

Comment: что вам не понятно?

Comment: Как выполнять действия в P-ичной системе счисления и что такое P-изображение? И если не тяжело приведите пожалуйста пример с перевода любого числа с 4 СС в 11 СС.

Comment: ну например число 3210(4) в (11). 
По формуле записываем: 3х4^3+2х4^2+1х4^1+0х4^0, однако эти операции (сложения/умножения) надо выполнять в 11-ричной СС

Comment: Откуда взялись 34 и 24 и 14 и 04?) И как выполнять действия в 11-ричной СС?

Comment: Там была звёздочка, а она воспринимается тут как элемент редактирования. Сейчас заменил на знак умножения через "х"